# Como retornar id de um registro que acabei de inserir usando Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Estou mexendo com Laravel a pouco tempo e estou com um problema...
Preciso retornar o id de uma tabela no banco de dados para alimentar a chave estrangeira de outra tabela e não estou conseguindo.

Como pego o id que foi inserido por último?

```
    $customer                 = new Customer();
    $customer->name_customer  = $request->input('name');
    $customer->cpf_customer   = $request->input('cpf');
    $customer->email_customer = $request->input('email');
    
    $result = $customer->save();
    
    $sales                    = new Sale();
    $sales->date_sale         = $formatDate;
    $sales->quant_sale        = $request->input('quantity');
    $sales->deduction_sale    = $finalValue;
    $sales->name_product_sold = $request->input('product');
    $sales->status_sale       = $request->input('status');
    $sales->sales_customer_id = $customer->customer_id;
 
    $result = $sales->save();
```

Criei o objeto **Customer** e estou tentando pegar o `customer_id` embaixo, mas está vindo como **`null`**

Laravel Framework 7.25.0
Mysql

Comment: Qual a versão do Laravel e do PHP que você está usando? Qual o banco de dados? Essas informações são importantes para a gente poder te ajudar. Se possível inclua essas informações na sua pergunta.

Comment: Se a minha resposta atendeu o que você queria, por favor, marque como resposta da sua pergunta para ficar como respondida.

Answer (score 0):

Se sua tabela estiver estruturada com o padrão do Laravel (usando "id") seria assim:

```
$customer                 = new Customer();
$customer->name_customer  = $request->input('name');
$customer->cpf_customer   = $request->input('cpf');
$customer->email_customer = $request->input('email');

$result = $customer->save();

$sales                    = new Sale();
$sales->date_sale         = $formatDate;
$sales->quant_sale        = $request->input('quantity');
$sales->deduction_sale    = $finalValue;
$sales->name_product_sold = $request->input('product');
$sales->status_sale       = $request->input('status');
$sales->sales_customer_id = $result->id;

$result = $sales->save();
```

Se você estiver feito um relacionamento seguindo também o padrão pode ser assim também

```
$customer                 = new Customer();
$customer->name_customer  = $request->input('name');
$customer->cpf_customer   = $request->input('cpf');
$customer->email_customer = $request->input('email');
$customer->save();

$sales                    = new Sale();
$sales->date_sale         = $formatDate;
$sales->quant_sale        = $request->input('quantity');
$sales->deduction_sale    = $finalValue;
$sales->name_product_sold = $request->input('product');
$sales->status_sale       = $request->input('status');
$customer->sales()->save($sales);
```

Isto é caso no seu modelo Costumer tiver um relacionamento chamado sales()
você pode fazer assim direto pois ja pega a chave estrangeira automaticamente.

Lembrando que eu falei sobre os "padrões do laravel" mas não há nada de errado de usar o seu próprio padrão.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method

Answer (score -1):

Depois de salvar, $data->id deverá ser o ultimo id inserido.

```
$data->save();
$data->id;
```

Também pode ser usado assim no seu caso:

```
$sales->sales_customer_id = $customer->id;
```

Mas tomo **muito cuidado** seu id precisa ser do timo **AUTO INCREMENTADO** senão pode dar erro, se for do tipo string.

Também não pode esquecer de definir a váriavel abaixo na MODEL como true senão vai retornar como vazio.

```
public $incrementing = true;
```

Por exemplo:

```php
    <?php
    
    class Voar extends Model
    {
        /**
         * Indicando se o ID é auto-incrementado.
         *
         * @var bool
         */
        public $incrementing = true;
    }
```

link para a documentação oficial do Laravel aqui: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent

Comment: perdoa amigo mas nao entendi, depois de pegar a chave estrangeira da tabela 'customer' eu preciso passar como parâmetro para para alimentar a tabela 'sale'...nesse caso eu passaria o "response()->json"?

Comment: Usando o código `$sales->sales_customer_id = $customer->id;` , mas precisa incluir na declaração da sua classe o parâmetro `public $incrementing = true;`